# After updating unity to latest version, the unity launcher is blank

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday I updated my unity to latest version..

Then the launcher is blank.

And when i open any .unity file.. It opens the editor with a error.

```
Error loading file:///C%3A%2FUsers%2FBuckyDroidz%2FAppData%2FRoaming%2FUnity%2FPackages%2Fnode_modules%2Funity-editor-home%2Fdist/index.html#/login
```

Unity is still working and running the project.. But unity launcher is not working

After searching on google I found a fix. I mean I have to add some file in package folder.. But there was a link to download those files and the link is dead...

Help Me!!

Comment: Did you update to the latest 5.4 version, or the latest 5.5 Beta version, infact which version.... ?

Comment: 5.4 @ParadoxForge ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your SO username, it looks like this is a problem with your computer username.The *D* in your name is probably "*Ď*" or some other character and Unity is having problem reading that file path(*C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Unity/Packages/node_modules/unity-editor-home/dist/index.html#/login*). This causes license check  to fail.

Two things to try:

**Method 1**.

Change your username

**A**.Change your name to valid English characters

**B**.Uninstall and install Unity again to recognize that change.

*If this does not fix your problem, do method 2*.

**Method 2**

Do manual Activation

**A**.Disconnect your internet/wifi.

**B**.Open Unity. Go to **Help** *->* **Manage License**

**C**.Click on **Manual Activation**.

**D**.Click on *Save License* or *Save License Request*(Depends on Unity version)

**E**.Connect to your internet/wifi.

**F**.Go to *https://license.unity3d.com/manual*  then upload that saved license there. Follow steps to on the website to create a license on that website. Make sure to chose free unity version as the license type. When everything is done, you will be able to download a key file. Download that file.

**G**.Disconnect your internet/wifi again.

**H**.Open Unity. Go to **Help** *->* **Manage License**

**I**.Click on **Manual Activation**.

**J**.Click on *Load License* then choose the file you downloaded from step F.

You can now connect to your internet/wifi again. Restart Unity and test if the problem is still there.

Comment: Uninstall Unity then install it then follow through the steps. I put two solutions. Please try both.

Comment: Yeah reinstalling unity solved the problem xD. Forgot to upvote

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with 2017.2 as well
To fix
go to C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\Packages

You can see 4 tgz files

1. unity-editor-home.0.8.30.tgz
2. unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.15.tgz
3. unityeditor-collab-history.0.6.14.tgz
4. unityeditor-collab-toolbar.0.7.15.tgz

Use an unarchive program (I used 7-zip file manager) to open each one of these and extract contents (dist folder and package.json file) to your Roaming folder
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules

After extract, the folder looks like this..
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unity-editor-home
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unityeditor-cloud-hub
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unityeditor-collab-history
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unityeditor-collab-toolbar

and unity-editor-home like below (one level subfolders shown)
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unity-editor-home\dist
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unity-editor-home\package.json
..\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages\node_modules\unity-editor-home\README.md